# Xamarin forms check accessibility focus on an element

Tags: xamarin.forms, focus, accessibility, event-listener, screen-readers

Is there a way to detect when an element receives the focus of a screen reader? Like an event listener or some such? And there is a way like to create a listener like this on my own?

What I would like to do is to play a sound when a certain element (like a frame that contains an image) receives the focus, instead of reading the accessibility name.

Comment: As I know, do not find the listener of the accessibility focus, you could check the Accessibility code sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-accessibility/, it used Automation Properties not find for a sound. For some touch, Focus method works well for come special control like entry, you could check the thread link. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126621/is-it-possible-to-set-focus-to-a-grid-element

Answer (score 1):

We can have a listener created for getting the focused event for a control.

eg: I have an Entry control named txtUserName. So we can code like below in the xaml.cs file.

```
    public MyPage()
    {
            InitializeComponent ();
            txtUserName.Focused += UserTextFocused;
            txtUserName.Unfocused += UserTextUnFocused;
    }

    private void UserTextFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do the required action
    }

    private void UserTextUnFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do the required action
    }
```

Comment: It is a different kind of focus, what I am looking for is a listener of the accessibility focus, the one that the screen reader use to read the elements on the screem